# how to print sorted multiple sentences alphabetically in python?

Tags: python, urllib

I am having trouble getting the output. I am getting unordered sentences as output and I need them alphabetically sorted.

```
import sys
import os
from urllib.request import Request
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError
import json


def  getMovieTitles(variable):
    # variable = raw_input()
    var = str(variable)

    for i in range(0, 10):
        page = str(1)
        url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=%s&page=%s" % (var, page)

# while(int(page)<int(page)+1):
        response = urlopen(url).read().decode('UTF-8')
        data = json.loads(response)
# response2 = urllib2.urlopen(url2)
        # data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
        # data = json.loads(response.json())

        print (data['data'][i]['Title'])



    for i in range(0,3):
        page = str(2)
        url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=%s&page=%s" % (var, page)

# while(int(page)<int(page)+1):
        response = urlopen(url).read().decode('UTF-8')
        data = json.loads(response)
        print (data['data'][i]['Title'])
    # print data2['data'][i]['Title']


getMovieTitles("spiderman")


      #output:
              Italian Spiderman
              Superman, Spiderman or Batman
              Spiderman
              Spiderman
              Fighting, Flying and Driving: The Stunts of Spiderman 3
              Spiderman and Grandma
              The Amazing Spiderman T4 Premiere Special 
              Amazing Spiderman Syndrome
              Hollywood's Master Storytellers: Spiderman Live
              Spiderman 5
              They Call Me Spiderman
              The Death of Spiderman
              Spiderman in Cannes
        #ouput required:
              Amazin Spiderman Syndrome
              Fighting, Flying and Driving: The Stunts of Spiderman 3
              Hollywood's Master Storytellers: Spiderman Live
              ....... and so on NOTICE THE FIRST LETTER IN OUTPUT 
                                    REQUIRED SECTION as its 
                            alphabetically ordered
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code that does any sorting. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your titles into a list `mylist` and then call `mylist.sort()`